# Consolidation of one column based on another

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a problem coming up with a solution on the following;
I have an excel spreadsheet with three key bits of information I need to sort by.

1. **ID/Acct number**. This number can be entered multiple times.
2. **Amount paid**.
3. **Date**. Even if there are multiple entries of the account number. The date will never change. Think of this date as an Account Creation date and not a date related to amount paid.

The problem is that when I consolidate, it is consolidating the date as well and throws my data off.

```
ID #    Date of Occurrence  Total inc
```

How can I consolidate the ID#'s into a single entry where it sums up "total inc" but leaves the Date of Occurrence alone?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Please post some sample data with desired output to help us to understand it.

Comment: I would create a separate table which just has ID# and the Date.

Then, you can consolidate the ID# and Amount Paid, and bring the date back after the consolidation with a lookup formula.

Comment: @DavePenn give us a sample data (fake ones), and how the output you want

Comment: @Vylix, I'm not the OP, mine was just a comment for the OP.

Comment: -Account ID    Date of Pay         Total inc
-1207873             1/9/2012              $0
-1208809              5/14/2012              $0
-1211594               6/29/2013             $7,621
-1211594        6/29/2013           $2,500
-1211594        6/29/2013           $20,000
-1211594        6/29/2013           $19,000

Comment: sorry, having trouble pasting example.